Set globale attribute from path variable
The application has defined the locale as the first part of the request URI. All controllers have defined @RequestMapping("/{locale}").
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/{locale}")
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping(value = "/",)
    public String index() {
        return "index/index";
    }
}

In the template I have links to routes, absolute URLs and static files.
<!-- Route -->
<a th:href="@{/}">[[#{nav.home}]]</a>

<!-- Absolute URL -->
<a th:href="${object.getPublicUrl()}">[[${object.getPath()}]]</a>

<!-- Static file -->
<img th:src="@{/images/name.jpeg}" />

I would like to set the locale before all routes in the templates. For example:
<a th:href="@{locale + /}">[[#{nav.home}]]</a>

Is it possible to define or set this globally? I do not want to set the attribute in every action with Model.
I have found Integration with RequestDataValueProcessor. But here I would have to exclude in processUrl to exclude absolute URL and static files. I am not sure if this is correct.

Use a UrlRewriteFilter to filter out the Locale and put it back in. Something like https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/. That way internally you have regular URLs and on the outside prefixed them with the Locale. (Which I think I already pointed you to in another question you asked earlier).

I have come up with a solution to both questions that works 95% of the time. But it feels wrong. I also think that this kind of language handling is not intended by Spring Core. There are different LocaleResolvers, but not when the language is part of the RequestURI.  In the Symfony framework (PHP) you can configure this language handling with a few lines. Thanks for your advice. I will take a look at the UrlRewriteFilter now. It also supports mod_rewrite syntax, which is good.
